# Add a CSS class to all images on a page that have a width less than 480px using DomDocument

Tags: php, wordpress, domdocument

I would like to add a CSS class to all images on the page (WordPress post/pages) that are below a certain width.

The following works but **setAttribute** is replacing all the class names in each img with the new one.

How can I add a new class to each image, without replacing the existing classes?

```
function add_class_to_small_images( $content ) {

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML( $content );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {

    $width = $image->getAttribute('width');

    if( $width < 480) {
        $image->setAttribute('class', 'this-will-be-the-class'); // the new class
    }
}

  $content = $dom->saveHTML();


return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_class_to_small_images');
```

Comment: The width in firebug is calculated based on the actual output in the browser, with php you'd need to fetch each image an process it with ImageMagick to find out the actual width. So the best way to go here would be using jQuery or any other JavaScript library.

Comment: @ThomasStachl Thank you. If I understand you correctly, you're saying it's not possible to use PHP to get an images true size. Bugger, wanted to avoid jQuery for this one.

Comment: @ThomasStachl Actually, now that I think about it, I might be ok with searching for the `width` attribute of each image as each image has one. Will give that a shot instead.

Comment: It's not that it isn't possible, you can use a PHP library called ImageMagick to find out the actual width (that's the same thing that's been used to create thumbnails for example and here is the link to the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagewidth.php). But I wouldn't advise it, as you only want to add a class it's easier to use jQuery: `$('img').each(function() { if ($(this).width() < 480) $(this).addClass('this-will-be-the-class') })`.

Comment: @ThomasStachl Thanks for the link. In my instance I didn't want to rely on too heavily on jQuery because it would mess up a lot of the formatting if a user has it turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this works. Grabbed the existing classes and added them back into the setAttribute with the new class I wanted. If anyone had a better method, please let me know.

```
function add_class_to_small_images( $content ) {

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML( $content );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {

    // get the widths of each image
    $width = $image->getAttribute('width');

    // the existing classes already on the images
    $existing_classes = $image->getAttribute('class');

    // the class we're adding
    $new_class = ' this-will-be-the-class';

    // the existing classes plus the new class
    $class_names_to_add = $existing_classes . $new_class;

    // if image is less than 480px, add their old classes back in plus our new class
    if( $width < 480) {
        $image->setAttribute('class', $class_names_to_add);
    }
}

  $content = $dom->saveHTML();


return $content;
}
```