# PHP: Reading DOM info of own HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

So, let's say I have only one file on my server called *index.php* :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <body style="background-color: orange;">
    <!-- On/Off button's picture -->
    <?php    
      echo ("<img id='button' src='data/button.jpg' alt='off'/>");
    ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, let's say I attach a JavaScript that changes the buttons ALT to ON when I click the button at some point.

How can I read the DOM elements on this page using PHP?
So far, I've found this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$main = $dom->getElementById('alt');
```

but I can't figure out how I would fit that in my code above, what page should I call loadHTML() for?

**How do I make PHP read DOM elements it generated using echo?**

Comment: PHP can't read the data once it has been output - and definitely not when JavaScript is running

Comment: implement [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979166/add-a-css-class-to-all-images-on-a-page-that-have-a-width-less-than-480px-using/11980089#11980089)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your button has id `button`, so searching for the id `alt` would return no results.

Second: The piece of php you found reads a page $html (probably `file_get_contents('some_url')`, puts it in the variable `dom` and parses it, searching for the id *alt*. In your case it would read your own page, breaking it down in pieces looking for that button.

Thats of no use if you can read the status with javascript on your own page. You can then pass it to php trough an ajax-call or by adding it to the url like `mypage.php?button=off`

Comment: AJAX is out of the question in my case. Doesn't loadHTML($html) load the HTLM page whose address is stored in $html (so I need `$html="index.html"` for example)?

Comment: But why oh why would you parse a whole page to acces that one element when you have it right in front of you on your own page. One line of javascript and you can do everything with it you want.

Comment: It's a [looooong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974014/php-and-javascript-sharing-a-unix-socket-between-php-programs-through-javascrip) story. Basically, javascript can't do everything, it doesn't allow for PHP programs to communicate throught it.

Comment: PHP is serverside, javascript is clientside. They can communicate, but generally speaking only if you 'ask' for it from the client-side by posting a form, placing an ajax-request or making an url-request. As I said before, you can add variables to the url, or maybe in your case an iframe could be the solution.

Comment: I'll look it up, but while PHP is serverside it's still run in a seperate process for each user that connects to the server. So, running the PHP script indefinetly and waiting for the JS to tell us what to do should be possible (without having to start a 2nd PHP process which AJAX does).

Answer (score 0):

$main = $dom->getElementById('button');